# How to upload MULTIPLE (stable) images?

Tags: support, images

How do I upload say 5 JPEG images into a question so that I do not need to
retype so many paragraphs in my question, and at the same time do not need provide the link to PDF of the entire book? What is the best way to provide these 5 images to other users who are supposed to reply?

Comment: I think this is a case of the XY problem. If your question cannot be concisely expressed without five images of paragraphs then it likely needs substantial rewriting.

Comment: I appreciate your concern for "users who are supposed to reply," but Readers will be more motivated to do so if they see you've thoughtfully written a Question in your own words rather than uploading images in order that you "do not need to retype so many paragraphs."

Comment: Let me add that even though it's annoying to copy text in a book by hand to include it in a question, it's actually an often-useful exercise: I've seen many cases where the confusion comes down to a missing word, and when you have to type the material out yourself that increases the chances of you seeing the issue on your own.

Answer (score 14):

Stack Exchange does not want you to do what you are trying to do:

- text input should be supplied in the normal way — not via images
- posts should be self-contained — essential content should not be confined to an external pdf

You need to revise the content you wish to post so that it doesn't require these things.